# PHP post data on input type="hidden"

Tags: php, html, post, input, get

Just a quick one, I've found that if you use `<input type="text" name="test" value="test" disabled></input>` the post data will not be sent. If you remove `disabled` then it works fine. Is there a way around this issue, without 
having to do something dirty like having 2 input fields (1 hidden to send the form data) and the other as disabled to show the user the value?

I've had a brief search on SA and most answers don't actually provide a solution, its mostly people getting `$_POST` and `$_GET` mixed up.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know as it almost feels satanic doing it the other way.

Thanks alot!

EDIT: after a little more searching, i managed to find a solution, see below.

Comment: There is also the `readonly` property for input fields, have you tried that?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I've literally just found the `readonly` property. Thanks man!

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Remember though that `readonly` doesn't work for `<select>` and indeed the only option to go with is a `disabled` `<select>` and a `hidden` value bearing `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more researching i have found the answer to my issue, Apparently input fields have a property called `readonly`, See code below:

```
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: So you have found the answer on your own within 3 minutes after you have posted the question whre the first comment here mentioned the readonly property

Comment: Yes, i found the answer just before he commented, to which I then responded stating i had just found the answer on another SA post. @Jer only responded with the name of the property so its not like he gave me the entire answer and i completely ripped it because that's not the case.